# showing undefined at the end of $.each of JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to filter data that I need for my project(I only want the date only). I have managed to loop through the JSON object and have it displayed. The only problem is, at the end of the loop, it shows undefined. I don't know why I am doing wrong. Here is an example of what I did

JS file

```
console.clear();

$.ajax({
  async: true,
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/n1cwx",
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, object) {
      //console.log(data);
      //console.log(object);
      $("body").append("<p>" + object.last_activity_at + "</p>");           
    });
  }
});
```

Output

```
2017-06-09T17:49:49.975+12:00

2017-07-13T08:59:20.023+12:00

2017-05-29T14:17:18.148+12:00

2017-05-21T22:19:07.951+12:00

2017-06-09T13:59:50.464+12:00

2017-06-13T08:18:30.340+12:00

2017-07-27T12:41:17.423+12:00

undefined
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxyZXm

Thanks!

Comment: Can it be that the api really gives ' undefined' back ? Seems like there's no problem with your code but maybe there was an error when the dates were submitted into the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last element in your JSON data is not an object, it is :

```
pages: "1"
```

Therefore, `object.last_activity_at` is undefined.

A workaround would be :

```
$.each(data, function (i, object) {
      if(!object.last_activity_at) return;
      $("body").append("<p>" + object.last_activity_at + "</p>");           
});
```

Comment: thansk so much! this works ok. I dont really much have control with the content of the JSON file so  really needed a work around it. Would accept your answer after few mins. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your API is adding one last property to the response (pages:1). This converts your array of objects into a keyed object. Because of this, now your loop is parsing "pages" as its final object which does **not** have the property you are trying to inject into HTML, hence **undefined**.

Fix your array, or ignore the last object value in your loop.

```
{ "pages":"1" } // No last_activity_at property here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an object containing 7 objects, and a key/value pair at the end, hence your error:

```
{  
   "0":{  },
   "1":{  },
   "2":{  },
   "3":{  },
   "4":{  },
   "5":{  },
   "6":{  },
   "pages":"1"
}
```

You should check to make sure that each object actually contains `last_activity_at` before trying to access it:

```
if ( typeof object !== 'undefined' && object.hasOwnProperty('last_activity_at') ) {
    $("body").append("<p>" + object.last_activity_at + "</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your array contains an object like this :

[image]

As you can see last item is

```
pages : 1 // causing problem
```

Hence last item is coming as undefined. So either remove that `pages : 1` or do like this :

```
console.clear();

$.ajax({
  async: true,
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/n1cwx",
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, object) {
      if(object.last_activity_at)
      $("body").append("<p>" + object.last_activity_at + "</p>");           
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not an array:

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 34,
    "description": "A collection of in houses",
    "default_branch": "master",
    "tag_list": [],
    "created_at": "2017-02-28T15:02:49.756+13:00",
    "last_activity_at": "2017-06-09T17:49:49.975+12:00",
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "creator_id": 13,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 99,
      "parent_id": 98
    },
    "star_count": 0,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "public_builds": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "permissions": {
      "project_access": null,
      "group_access": {
        "access_level": 40,
        "notification_level": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 38,
    "description": "Scripts",
    "default_branch": "master",
    "tag_list": [],
    "created_at": "2017-02-28T15:05:40.505+13:00",
    "last_activity_at": "2017-07-13T08:59:20.023+12:00",
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "creator_id": 13,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 99,
      "parent_id": 98
    },
    "star_count": 0,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "public_builds": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "permissions": {
      "project_access": null,
      "group_access": {
        "access_level": 40,
        "notification_level": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 49,
    "description": "Dashboard",
    "default_branch": "master",
    "tag_list": [],
    "created_at": "2017-04-26T14:50:59.051+12:00",
    "last_activity_at": "2017-05-29T14:17:18.148+12:00",
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "creator_id": 14,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 99,
      "parent_id": 98
    },
    "star_count": 0,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "public_builds": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "permissions": {
      "project_access": null,
      "group_access": {
        "access_level": 40,
        "notification_level": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 51,
    "description": "",
    "default_branch": "master",
    "tag_list": [],
    "created_at": "2017-05-18T16:33:48.041+12:00",
    "last_activity_at": "2017-05-21T22:19:07.951+12:00",
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "creator_id": 19,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 24,
      "parent_id": null
    },
    "avatar_url": null,
    "star_count": 0,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "public_builds": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "permissions": {
      "project_access": {
        "access_level": 40,
        "notification_level": 3
      },
      "group_access": null
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 60,
    "description": "",
    "default_branch": "master",
    "tag_list": [],
    "created_at": "2017-06-09T13:59:50.464+12:00",
    "last_activity_at": "2017-06-09T13:59:50.464+12:00",
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "creator_id": 14,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 99,
      "parent_id": 98
    },
    "star_count": 0,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "public_builds": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "permissions": {
      "project_access": null,
      "group_access": {
        "access_level": 40,
        "notification_level": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "5": {
    "id": 62,
    "description": "Mattermost Android App",
    "default_branch": "master",
    "tag_list": [],
    "created_at": "2017-06-13T08:18:30.340+12:00",
    "last_activity_at": "2017-06-13T08:18:30.340+12:00",
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "creator_id": 13,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 99,
      "parent_id": 98
    },
    "star_count": 0,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "public_builds": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "permissions": {
      "project_access": null,
      "group_access": {
        "access_level": 40,
        "notification_level": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "6": {
    "id": 283,
    "description": "",
    "default_branch": null,
    "tag_list": [],
    "created_at": "2017-07-24T16:08:01.893+12:00",
    "last_activity_at": "2017-07-27T12:41:17.423+12:00",
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "lfs_enabled": false,
    "creator_id": 23,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 99,
      "parent_id": 98
    },
    "star_count": 0,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "open_issues_count": 1,
    "public_builds": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "permissions": {
      "project_access": null,
      "group_access": {
        "access_level": 40,
        "notification_level": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "pages": "1"
}
```

It is an object that happens to have a few attributes that happen to be numeric strings, plus an attribute named 'pages'. `$.each()` is looping through all the keys of the map, including 'pages'.

Ways to sove the problem would be:

- You could generate a less confusing JSON, which will save you from future headaches;
- You could filter the keys beforehand, picking only the numeric ones;
- You could, perhaps, inside `each()` check if the key is a string;
- Another option, as others already mentioned, would be to skip the objects that don't have the key you need.

Comment: But that doesn't quite explain or solve the problem.